# Number of non-isomorphic codes

Tags: coding-theory, graph-isomorphism

We have number of non-isomorphic graphs given in http://planetmath.org/enumeratinggraphs

Over an alphabet $q$ how many non-isomorphic $[n,k,d]_q$ codes are possible particularly in the special case of $d=n-k+1$ (MDS case)?

The paper here provides number of non-isomorphic $[n,k]_2$ codes without restricting distance.

My question has distance restriction.

Comment: I would think that this question is much more likely to get an answer in MathOverflow. If it doesn't get an answer here in a few days, you should ask it there.